# Min distance of one point to set of points Django ORM

Tags: python, django, database, geometry, django-orm

I am trying to calculate minimum distances of one point to set of points.
For example if there are 3 places `A, B, C` in the set and the wanted place is `D`, I want  `min(dist(A, D), dist(B, D), dist(C, D)`.
Here is my place model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=False)
```

Here is my query which seems not to work:

```
places_with_distance = Place.objects.annotate(
            distance=(
                Subquery(places_set.annotate(
                    distance_to_place_in_set=(
                        Min(
                            (F('latitude') - OuterRef('latitude')) * (F('latitude') - OuterRef('latitude')) +
                            (F('longitude') - OuterRef('longitude')) * (F('longitude') - OuterRef('longitude'))
                        )
                    )
                ).values('distance_to_place_in_set'))))
```

The problem is that the distance gets calculated only for the first item of the `places_set`(e.g. only `dist(A, D)` but not `dist(B, D)`, ...).

Thanks!

Comment: please, read your post, and fix issues. it is not clear what you want exactly..  If you want min , why u use order_by?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov Thanks for your reply. I am trying to sort them at the end but it was not part of this problem. I changed that part to clarify the question.